# PHP Single Type Collection

Tags: php, object-oriented, collections

I have implemented a collection class that stores a single type of value.

At the moment it is immutable.

```php
abstract class Collection implements Iterator
{

    /** @var int */
    protected $position = 0;
    /** @var array */
    private $items = [];

    public function next()
    {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return isset($this->items[$this->position]);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    protected function add($item)
    {
        return $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    protected function get($index)
    {
        return $this->items[$index];
    }
}
```

`DateTimeIterator` guarantees that when iterated over it will only return the specified type.

```php
interface DateTimeIterator extends Iterator
{

    public function current(): DateTimeInterface;
}
```

The constructor of `DateTimeCollection` ensures that the collection only stores values that implement `DateTimeInterface`.

```php
class DateTimeCollection extends Collection implements DateTimeIterator
{

    public function __construct(iterable $values = [])
    {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if (!$value instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
                throw new TypeError('DateTimeCollection only accepts ' .
                    'items that implement DateTimeInterface');
            }
            $this->add($value);
        }
    }

    public function current(): DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->get($this->key());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Collection` is not really immutable if you can add items to it :)

---

You should explicitly define either abstract or simple default implementation (i.e. that doesn't enforce return data type) for `current()` method on `Collection`.

---

I would suggest using `$this->key()` within `valid()`

```
public function valid()
{
    return isset($this->items[$this->key()]);
}
```

This is consistent with your usage in `current()` in inheriting classes and consistent with iterator interface.  This also allows for override of `key()` in inheriting classes if there ever was such a need for this.

---

Consider explicitly specifying abstract constructor in `Collection` class (or again a simple default constructor (i.e. just setting position to O)).  You should explicitly set position to 0 in constructor in some manner.

---

You might consider exposing a `length()` function on your collection since you are providing functionality beyond basic iteration.  This would allow you to do things like perhaps return new index value to caller on `add()`.

```
public function length() {
    return count($this->items[]);
}

protected function add($item)
{
    $this->items[] = $item;
    // return index of new item
    return $this->length() - 1;
}
```

---

You also should consider validating input parameter passed to get against valid method as being within range of keys.

```
protected function get($index)
{
    if(!$this->valid($index)) {
        throw new OutOfBoundsException(
            'Index passed to get() is invalid.'
        );
    }
    return $this->items[$index];
}
```